# Visual Basic 2013 Preview Window

Tags: javascript

I've just switched from Khan Academy's version of Javascript (They have their code on the left side and on the right side you can actively see what your code is doing. If you wrote code on the left for a bouncing ball you would visually see the ellipse bouncing on the right screen) to Visual Studio 2013 and am having a hard time finding a "Preview Screen" so I can actively see what my code is producing.

Any tips or a guide to make this window (if it exists) open, or another program that works much better than Visual Basic in the way that Khan Academy did.

Comment: It's a nice concept for simple applications. But constantly running code can lead to trouble ( when you have a lot and it's not a simple task ). Just run the code when you want to to test. Mainly because it makes sense in some cases, but not in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one, at least in "stock" VS. What you might want to look at are "live reload" programs or the like: http://alphapixels.com/prepros/